# How to convert a data scheme to image and save

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

As for the title, I have trouble saving images in the data scheme.

This is my code, but it doesn't work at all.

```cs
        [Route("api/account/update_avatar")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Update()
        {
            if (AppCommon.LoginAuth("Web") == false)
            {
                return AppCommon.ResponseMessage("login-authentication-failed");
            }

            HttpResponseMessage Response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            var EncodedImage = Context.Request.Params["image"].TypeString();

            var Id = Context.Session["UserId"].TypeString() + ".png";

            var StoragePath = Common.PathCombine(AppConfig.AvatarStoragePath, Id);

            try
            {
                // From StackOverflow

                // Split the string to escape the real data
                var b64 = EncodedImage.Split(",".ToCharArray(), 2);

                // Convert the base 64 String to byte array
                byte[] byteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(b64[1]);

                // Open a stream from the byte array
                MemoryStream ImgStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                // Generate the image from the stream
                Image DecodedImage = Image.FromStream(ImgStream);

                // Save the image
                DecodedImage.Save(StoragePath);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                return AppCommon.ResponseMessage("internal-error"); // This does returned
            }

            return AppCommon.ResponseMessage("success");
        }
```

There is no problem with data. I posted a data scheme with the script

```js
  var image = $("#photo");

  // jquery cropper
  var scheme = image
    .cropper("getCroppedCanvas", {
      width: 600,
      height: 600,
    })
    .toDataURL("image/png");

  fastui.coverShow("waiting-cover");

  // Customized Ajax, never mind.
  $ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/account/update-avatar",
    async: true,
    data: "image=" + scheme,
    callback: function (data) {
      if (data == "internal-error") {
        fastui.textTips(lang.user.tips["operation-failed"]);
      } else if (data == "success") {
        window.parent.fastui.iconTips("tick");

        window.setTimeout(function () {
          window.parent.fastui.windowClose("avatar");
        }, 500);
      } else {
        fastui.textTips(lang.user.tips["operation-failed"]);
      }
    },
  });
```

The program has proper permission to write files.
This has nothing to do with my front-end.

If someone can answer my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: "it doesn't work at all" - What does not work at all? What error do you get? Do the input values look correct? Does the base64 string look correctly encoded and of the correct size?

Comment: What's the point of all this code? Why not just post a binary file? There's no reason to encode images to post them to ASP.NET. There's no reason to directly access the `Request` object either. You could have used a `byte[] image` parameter to get the data, or an `IFormFile` if a FORM POST was used

Comment: You don't need a Data URL in JavaScript either. You can post the Blob as-is, or pass it as a parameter to a FORM post

Comment: [Upload Files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) shows how you can handle form uploads of both small and big files. If you don't want to use form posts, you can post the raw data. In ASP.NET you can read that data through the `Request.Body` steam. No conversion is necessary

Comment: The [Sending binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#sending_binary_data) section in Mozilla's `Sending and Receiving Binary Data` shows how to send binary data from JavaScript. Again, no conversions are needed

Comment: `There is no problem with data` in the end, there is. None of this code is really necessary. In fact, jQuery-Cropper's [getCroppedCanvas docs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md#getcroppedcanvasoptions) show how to use just `.toBlob()` to get a blob and post it

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the scripts.

- Firstly, if you are trying to post a string with the character '+', the character will be replaced with space.

```js
var scheme = image
    .cropper("getCroppedCanvas", {
      width: 600,
      height: 600,
    })
    .toDataURL("image/png").replaceAll('+', '@');
```

```cs
var EncodedImage = Context.Request.Params["image"].TypeString().Replace('@', '+');
```

- Secondly, if the path which contains the image doesn't exist, the image won't be saved but throw an exception.

```cs
            if (!Directory.Exists(AppConfig.AvatarStoragePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AppConfig.AvatarStoragePath);
            }
```

That's my solution, thanks

Comment: The problem is using a Data URL instead of a Blob in JavaScript, and trying to retrieve raw data from the Request object instead of using parameters in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use a Data URL or deal with its many problems. As jQuery-Cropper's [getCroppedCanvas docs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md#getcroppedcanvasoptions) show, it's possible to get a Blob from a Canvas object and post it either as raw binary or as a file in a FORM post.

```
image.cropper("getCroppedCanvas", {
      width: 600,
      height: 600,
    })
     .toBlob((blob) => {
         const formData = new FormData();
          // Pass the image file name as the third parameter if necessary.
          formData.append('croppedImage', blob, 'User123.png');

          // Use `jQuery.ajax` method for example
          $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success() {
              console.log('Upload success');
            },
            error() {
              console.log('Upload error');
            },
          });
        }/*, 'image/png' */);
```

On ASP.NET Core's side, the files in a FORM post are available as `IFormFile` objects :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(IFormFile croppedImage )
    {

        ....
        using(var targetStream=File.OpenWrite(StoragePath))
        {
            await croppedImage.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
        }
        return Ok("success");
    }
```

Uploading files, both small and large, is described in [Upload Files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

If you use the old ASP.NET Web API:

1. it's time to upgrade to ASP.NET Core. .NET Old is essentially in maintenance mode, and soon [even .NET 4.6.1 will be out of support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/).
2. The code is more complicated. This is documented in [Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#file-upload).

In this case, the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` class will store uploaded files to the `root` location based on the posted file name

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    ...
    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    // Read the form data.
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    ...
}
```

If you want to generate the name on the server you need to call [ReadAsMultipartAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834957(v=vs.118)) without a provider. This returns a [MultipartMemoryStreamProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995282(v=vs.108)) , whose [Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995276(v=vs.108)) property contains the files as [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193687(v=vs.118)) objects which, finally, allow you to save them:

```
var provider=await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
foreach(var cnt in provider.Contents)
{
    using(var targetStream=File.OpenWrite(somePath);
    {
        await cont.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was solved successfully in ASP.NET with your solution.